# Looking for old black and white SF movie regarding a alien laboratory underneath a small bridge

Tags: story-identification

When I was 6 years old I saw this black and white SF movie and it made a big impression on me. 
It tells the storybabot normal looking people that lure innocent people to a small bridge in someones backyard and then they get sucked into a alien laboratory. The only thing that distinguish the good people from the bad ones is a mark in the back of their necks. The story looks a lot like the 1953 "Invaders from Mars" but that is not the one I'm looking for. I hope you can help me. Kind regards

Comment: Can you provide any more details at all? What did the mark on the back of the neck look like? When people get "sucked in" to the laboratory, how does this happen (through the ground, through a trap door, via teleportation)? In what ways did this movie resemble "Invaders from Mars," and it what ways did it differ?